# Classic ASP conditional database driven drop down menu

Tags: javascript, ms-access, asp-classic

I know what I want to do but don't know how to do it.  I've got a database of doctors and when filling out a form, want the second drop down list to automatically be populated based on the first choice.

So let's say I select "Primary Care Doctor" (this is dynamic from the database, I have that part figured out).
The second drop down list would automatically populate from the database where all the specialties are "Primary Care Doctor"

I've attached the code I have so far as well as the database structure.

I have an access database named physicians.mdb the table that the physicians are being pulled from is table.  The fields are: physician and specialty (there's also an ID field that's the primary key).

Comment: `I've attached the code I have so far as well as the database structure.` . where ?

Comment: If you want this to be a dynamic thing -- i.e. the form isn't submitted between the first and second dropdown -- then you'll need to use javascript. There are many approaches possible, but what I like best (because the no-javascript fallback is automatic) is to code the dropdown list with option groups, and then use a jquery plugin that converts the optgroups to a linked dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your attachment but basically you want a query to load the second combo box like `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [Physicians] WHERE [SPECIALITY]='Primary Care Dcotor'`. See how you go from there, or give us more details.